# R - Should I use rasters to plot this data onto a map?

Tags: r, plot, dataframe, r-raster

I have a 5 column dataframe that I'm trying to make into something like a density plot. Each row in this dataframe represents a cell in a grid that maps onto a geographic area. Let's call the dataframe columns A, B, C, D, and E. Column A contains the ID of the cell. Column B contains its longitude. Column C contains its latitude. Columns D and E contain numerical values that are associated with the grid cell.

What I'm trying to do is plot the values of Column D (or E, but let's just use D as an example) onto a geographic map (preferably a google map) using the coordinates from Column B and C such that each grid cell is accurately placed on the map and has a color that corresponds to its value in Column D. So, for example, cells with higher values of D would be red while cells with lower values of D would be grey or something

I tried using a raster to do it but I've only known about rasters since yesterday and online resources have been confusing, but that may be due to my general ignorance of how R works ( [here's one source I looked at that has a picture of a similar map coloring that I am looking for](https://pakillo.github.io/R-GIS-tutorial/#raster)). The documentation is similarly impenetrable for an amateur like myself

I tried doing:

```
attempt <- raster(dataframe$D, dataframe$B, dataframe$C)
```

but that didn't seem to help. It just gave me an error message that said

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : unable to find an inherited method for
```

`function ‘raster’ for signature ‘"numeric"’`

Should I be trying to use a raster for this? If so, how do I get this to work? If not, is there a better technique for doing something so seemingly simple?

Thanks for taking the time to read this

Comment: Let's see a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Use rasterFromXYZ(dataframe) - the x and y coords must be the first two columns. Much more efficient methods are available but depend on you having the grid definition (resolution, offset, projection) in hand, which you should anyway. Ad hoc grids in tables is a recipe for problems.